# How can I batch select from several tables with jdbctemplate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I have the following query:

```
select name_table.name, age_table.age, address_table.address
from 
name_table name_table,
age_table age_table,
address_table address_table
where 
name_table.id = age_table.id
 and age_table.id = address_table.id
 and name_table.new_date between ?(start_date) and ?(end_date)
```

How can i use JDBCTemplate to get the needed data in batches? The start_date and end_date are variables.

Comment: What do you mean in batches? What is wrong with a list or streaming the result? What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is a simplified query, the proper one has about 20 parameters and the whole data set is about 1 million in size

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. What do you mean with batches? I would suggest using a `Stream` as that will lazily load the entries while you iterate over them and process them. That way you only always have a few results in memory to process. While with paging the query and logic becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your query is not correct:
from the syntax point of view "date" is a reserved word and
from the logic point of view, you are doing a cross table join over the 3 tables because you don't have any condition to join them in the WHERE clause (and you should better do it using standard ANSI join).
Second if your intent is to have the table names be parameters of the template, the answer is NO: table names and column names can't be parameters of a query.
This has been answered several times on stackoverflow, including by AskTOM site's guys, explaining in details why: mainly the data structure of the result must be known at parse time.

Comment: First, I've edited the query, and now it works fine.
Second, that was not the question I've asked, I need to have this select get the data in batches, as in 10, 20 per the call of the method, however, I don't know the id's that I would get from these tables

Comment: You can use "OFFSET ? FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY" syntax if your ORACLE version supports it, and you need to add an ORDER BY , if older ORACLE version, you have to add a column 'ROWNUM AS rn" and of course an ORDER BY and put the query in a subquery, the surrounding query having the criteria on the new rn column: "WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?".